# Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key on rake test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-web-services, railstutorial.org

I'm doing chapter 11 of hartle's tutorial.
When I ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` I got this error:

```
Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
```

I solved it with the answer in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949158/heroku-missing-required-arguments-aws-access-key-id-aws-secret-access-key-f/27950864#comment48059596_27950864) and migrate successfully.but now when I run

```
bundle exec rake test
```

It gives me:

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
```

This is my carrierwave file:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['S3_KEY'],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['S3_SECRET'],
    :region                 => ENV['S3_REGION'],
    :endpoint               => ENV['S3_ENDPOINT']
  }

  if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
    config.root = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads/#{DateTime.now.to_f}.#{rand(999)}.#{rand(999)}"
  else
    config.storage = :fog
  end

  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads/#{DateTime.now.to_f}.#{rand(999)}.#{rand(999)}"
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
  config.fog_public     = false
  config.fog_attributes = {}
end
```

I tested the answer in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995164/missing-required-arguments-aws-access-key-id-aws-secret-access-key) and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you add the file from which the ENV variables are being loaded.

Comment: Sorry I'm so new to rails...Where are they?

Answer (score 0):

I would set these in the test helper:

```
ENV['S3_KEY'] = 'S3_KEY'
ENV['S3_SECRET'] = 'S3_SECRET'
ENV['S3_REGION'] = 'S3_REGION'
ENV['S3_ENDPOINT'] = 'S3_ENDPOINT'
```

Alternately, you can do

```
if ! Rails.env.test?
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['S3_KEY'],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['S3_SECRET'],
    :region                 => ENV['S3_REGION'],
    :endpoint               => ENV['S3_ENDPOINT']
  }
end
```

But I think the first is better because it does not pollute your production code with test code.

Comment: You mean I have to create a new helper file for carrierwave?

Comment: No, update your test_helper.rb or update your carrierwave config file.